# What is the font size of the references section in the amsart class?

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize, amsart

Does anyone happen to know what the default fontsize of the references section in the `amsart` class is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `thebibliography` environment of `amsart` uses the `\bibliofont` macro which defaults to `\footnotesize`. Here's the relevant code snippet from `amsart.cls`:

```
\newcommand{\bibliofont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\@bibtitlestyle}{%
  \@xp\section\@xp*\@xp{\refname}%
}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \@bibtitlestyle
  \normalfont\bibliofont\labelsep .5em\relax
  \renewcommand\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}\let\p@enumiv\@empty
  \list{\@biblabel{\theenumiv}}{\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \usecounter{enumiv}}%
  \sloppy \clubpenalty\@M \widowpenalty\clubpenalty
  \sfcode`\.=\@m
}{%
  \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist
}
```